# how to insert an item in Combobox(dropdown) with value in winforms

Tags: winforms, combobox

This is a silly question.

but I searched a lot in Google but not found any good solution for this.

If we write

```
ddlReleaseMngr.Items.Insert(0, "Naibedya Kar");
```

This will insert a item in the dropdown but the value of the item is ZERO.

I want to inset an item in the dropdown with some value.

if I do

```
ddlBA.DataSource = tblBA;
ddlBA.DisplayMember = "Name";
ddlBA.ValueMember = "UserID";
```

by using above query we can set value to each item.

Like this I want to set a value for item.

Please help me

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The value of the item is not ZERO. The index is 0.

You can get the VALUE of the checkbox item by using:

```
ddlReleaseMngr.SelectedItem.ToString();
```

Which would give you "Naibedya Kar".

You can create an integer variable and assign it a value using the selected item like so:

```
int myvar = 0;

if(ddlReleaseMngr.SelectedIndex == 0)
{
    myvar = 5; //or whatever value you would like
}
```

or use a switch statement:

```
switch (ddlReleaseMngr.SelectedIndex)
{
case 0: 
    Console.WriteLine("Case 1: " + ddlReleaseMngr.SelectedItem.ToString());
    myvar = 0;//whatever value you would like
    break;
case 1:
    Console.WriteLine("Case 2");
    break;
default:
    Console.WriteLine("Default case");
    break;
}
```

Comment: i think value also ZERO.

If we write ddlReleaseMngr.SelectedValue then it will give zero

Comment: Are you not able to use the value of the selected item?

Comment: yes, i think i am not setting the value of the item.

how to set the value of the item while inserting to combobox.

Comment: You are setting the value when you insert an item in the combobox. If you would like a different value other than what is dispalyed, suppose you would like "Naibedya Kar" to equal a different string or int, you can use a switch statement to assign different values

Answer (score 0):

Why not `Items.Add` instead of `Items.Insert` like:

```
ddlReleaseMngr.Items.Add("Naibedya Kar");
```

Comment: then if i write ddlReleaseMngr.SelectedValue then it will give ZERO.

how to set the value of the item while inserting to combobox.